# Tkinter Python Entry state attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to check if the users cursor is in a text box by checking the Entries state value. However, I get "AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute 'state'". How do I check if the users cursor is in a textbox?

```
import os

from Tkinter import *

textboxes = []

def read_textboxes():
    for e in textboxes:
        print e.state

root = Tk()
for i in range(5):
    textboxes.append(Entry(root))
    textboxes[i].insert(0,"I am textbox #"+str(i))
    textboxes[i].grid(row = i,column = 0)
button = Button(root,text = "Read Textboxes",command = read_textboxes)
button.grid(row = len(textboxes),columnspan = 99,pady = 10)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `focus_get()` on the root to get the widget that currently has the focus.

```
def read_textboxes():
    in_focus = root.focus_get()
    for e in textboxes:
        print e == in_focus
```